# User addon and preload replace

Tags: preload-replace

I'm using preload replace to show a specific entry for a user, but the variable always displays the first option in the list. What am I doing wrong?

```
{exp:user:profile} {categories group_id="5"} {category_body}

{if {category_id} =="10"}{preload_replace:entryId="10"}
{if:elseif {category_id} =="11"}{preload_replace:entryId="9"}
{if:elseif {category_id} =="8"}{preload_replace:entryId="8"}
{if:else}{preload_replace:entryId="7"}{/if}

{/category_body} {/categories} {/exp:user:profile}
```

Answer (score 1):

**None** of your conditionals are affecting the value of your preload-replace.

Preload replace processing happens very early in the template parsing engine. The engine simply applies the first value you give. You can't assign preload replace variables dynamically.

From the docs:

> ExpressionEngine allows you to assign text to be replaced prior to a template being parsed, to save time typing and editing certain bits of text that might get used multiple times. Preload Replacements act as a straight string replacement for use later in the same template.

I personally have always solved my problems without this add-on, but it seems that most people use Stash as an easy way of getting around and setting variables in templates (which is against the point of a template):

https://github.com/croxton/Stash

Read the Stash docs and maybe it'll work for you, but I would recommend rethinking your execution as I would bet you can just avoid what you're trying to do using the native engine.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

As above I decided to put the following in a partial template:

```
{exp:user:profile} {categories group_id="5"} {category_body}
    {category_id}
{/category_body} {/categories} {/exp:user:profile}
```

Which allowed me to bring this into the page template:

```
{if { [name-of-partial-template] }=="10"}

  ...entry_id="10"...

{/if}
```

And so on